# Network interface statistics: tx_dropped value always 0

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I am writing a program that collects and displays network interface metrics located in the `/sys/class/net/` folder.

When I was reading about the meaning of `rx_dropped` value, I came to the conclusion that this value as many possible causes, such as the ones specified in the first answer of this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/528290/ifconfig-eth0-rx-dropped-packets

However, I cannot find any information on the `tx_dropped` value. I first though it would be related to TCP segments sent that did not get an Aknowledge and would therefore be dropped from the queue.

However, I was running `curl 8.8.7.5`, which would obviously result in retransmissions that I could watch in Wireshark, but the tx_dropped value remained 0.

Actually, in all the times I've run my program, I've never seen `tx_dropped` with a value other than `0`.

What situation would make `tx_dropped` increase?

Answer (score 0):

The `tx_dropped` (and `rx_dropped`) counters are driver specific and you have to check documentation or source of the code the driver you're using to figure out what those fields exactly mean.

For example, the `tg3` driver used for 10G Intel NICs has only following codepath to increase the `tx_dropped` counter: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fb054096aea0576f0c0a61c598e5e9676443ee86/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/tg3.c#L8139

I seems to be that most of the locations that end up calling `goto drop;` are related to TSO and GSO offloading or about ignoring packets with VLAN tags because of failing checksum. Other than those, only DMA memory allocation failure should cause `tx_dropped` to increase.

If you're seeing `tx_dropped` increasing, I'd recommend trying to disable all offloading features of the NIC and see if that helps.